# run a .sh script from its own root using java

Tags: java, bash, shell, processbuilder

I have a shell script in a different directory than my java files. This script contains only `ls` which prints the files in the current directory. When I run the java project it prints the files in the root of the java project not the root of shell script. I want it to print the files in the root of the shell script.

Java code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/omar/ros_ws/baxter3.sh");
Process p = pb.start();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [ProcessBuilder.directory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory%28java.io.File%29%20%22ProcessBuilder.directory), you probably want

```
String path = "/home/omar/ros_ws/baxter3.sh";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(path);
pb.directory(new File(path).getParent());
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. This works
I just replaced the 3rd line with: 
pb.directory(new File(path).getParentFile());

Answer (score 1):

You then should set the working directory of your `ProcessBuilder` instance to the directory you want to watch. You can do is using its method `directory(File directory)`.
See [Javadoc of ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.htm)

so before `pb.start()`, define a File for your Directory and assign it to the instance of ProcessBuilder.

```
        File myDir = new File("/home/omar/ros_ws");
        pb.directory(myDir);
        pb.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution: The command `ls` can be run with multiple arguments. One of which is a file argument which can be a directory.

From the [`ls` man page](http://ss64.com/bash/ls.html):

```
# List the contents of your home directory
$ ls ~
```

Thus, just pass your shell script the directory you have hard coded in your java code: `"/home/omar/ros_ws/"` and access it in your shell script via `$1`.

So your shell script will look something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls $1
```

And call your shell script from java via:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/omar/ros_ws/baxter3.sh /home/omar/ros_ws/");
// other code omitted for brevity
```